# A chrome extension detects page title change

Tags: google-chrome, title, detection

**My problem is:** I need an extension for chrome that detects, when a page title changes to a certain string.

**For example:** Original page title: "You have no emails". When I get an email, it will say: "You got an e-mail! (1)". And when the extension sees that the title changed to my string ("You got an e-mail! (1)") it makes 1 beep sound.
If you'd get another email, title would be: "You got an e-mail! (2)", and it would beep 2 times now.

If anyone can tell an already made extansion with this function, or can tell, how to make something like that, please help me!